# checkbox-inline placing checkbox over text instead of beside

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add checkboxes to my form but the bootstrap class "checkbox-inline" does not seem to be working for me.

Here is the code:

```
<strong>Styles:</strong>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :style_ids, Style.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
<% end %>
<br><br>

<strong>Ingredients:</strong>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :ingredient_ids, Ingredient.all, :id, :name do |cbi| %>
  <% cbi.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cbi.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cbi.text} %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the outcome:

[image: Checkboxes]

Any help on this would be much appriciated, been pulling my hair out over this.

Edit: After going through the bootstrap docs, it appears checkbox-inline and radio-inline have been dropped. I just need to figure out how to get the checkboxes beside each label

Edit 2: Figured it out! in my css I had

```
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I removed this and my forms broke, but my checkboxes were in the right place! So instead I just did

```
.input_checkbox input {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

--and everything is finally fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with Bootstrap 4 and two inline checkboxes. It should not be so hard to implement this structure with Ruby:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <strong>Styles:</strong>

  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="2">Greek
  </label>
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="3"> Chinese
  </label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30c40odf/

Comment: No luck here, best I got was getting them above the Label, instead of overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :style_ids, Style.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
  <%= cb.label  { "#{cb.check_box} #{cb.text}".html_safe } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Like the previous suggestion,  this one gets the checkboxes above, but not beside

Comment: Still just shows up on top, which honestly is still much better than before. Might have to settle.

My form starts off with 

`<div class="row">
  <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">`

Could that be interfering?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Styles:</label>

      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :style_ids, Style.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
        <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

I think this will help